# Handling unpredictable json response when working with swift codable

Tags: ios, json, parsing, swift4, codable

Sometimes my JSON response is like this

```
  {
 "products": [
             {
          "pId": "3564225",
           "name": "Maxi Skirt",
           "slug": "maxi-skirt",
            "sku": "s-navy",
            "priority": 10,
            "images": [

      ]
    },
    {
      "pId": "299328304",
      "name": "Necklace Setjewellery",
      "slug": "american-diamond-necklace-setjewellery",
      "sku": "free-size-purple",
      "priority": 10,
      "images": [

      ]
    }],
    "total": 2
}
```

And Sometimes it looks like this

```
{
  "products": [

  ],
  "total": 0
}
```

Swift decoder throws following error when parsing empty array response

```
"*Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: 
"The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 
"JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." 
UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}*"
```

How do I write a swift codable struct to handle multiple response JSON like these above?

PS: I can't change anything from server side.

Comment: The first JSON is invalid (a `]` is missing) however the error message should be *Badly formed array*, the second is valid.

Comment: Thanks i fixed the json @vadian

Comment: Then the error is somewhere else. Both JSON are valid.

Comment: there is no error in the json , i need swift codable struct to handle these two json responses (in a single model file).

Answer (score 1):

Both JSON objects are valid and can be decoded into

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let products : [Product]
    let total: Int
}

struct Product: Decodable {
    let pId, name, slug, sku : String
    let priority : Int
    let images : [Image]
}

struct Image: Decodable {
    let url : URL
}
```

As `images` is empty I just assume that there is an URL. Change it to the real property name(s) and type(s)

Answer (score -1):

Just refer the following link...
https://medium.com/xcblog/painless-json-parsing-with-swift-codable-2c0beaeb21c1

You will get all the stuffs about your issues and more informations in order to decrease further issues and improve your code structure.

Comment: hmm.. it is just simple tutorial to work with codable , doesnt give any information on handling multiple json reponses.

Comment: The linked article suggests to make all properties carelessly optional. That's pretty bad habit and defeats the powerful error descriptions of `Codable`. Rather than *nothing happens* catch all possible errors and inform the user (or the developer).